# Matching string

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I have done a bare minimum of javascript coding via code academy. I also help build spreadsheets in a family business, and we are working on new spreadsheets for 2017 (late!!) with additional capabilities which make function calls within the sheet very unwieldy. Right now experimenting with very simple custom function intending to work up to a few I need to use. Ran into problems so cut out everything from first script except the problem area.

commission(platform, amount) takes a name and numerical amount respectively. Based on these values I will be setting up commission formulas. Discovered a problem matching the name. After deleting all but the problem area, all I have is:

```
function commission(platform, amount) {

    return platform=="AB";

};
```

It is run from spreadsheet as:

(called from cell e4) `=commission(c4,d4)`

The value returned is FALSE.

c4 contains the text AB
d4 (irrelevant right now) contains 1000

The problem arose with `if(platform == "AB") {.......`

The function was not evaluating the condition as true. When I rewrote it to return the value of platform it did indeed return "AB" in cell e4 from which the function was called.

So the variable  clearly does read (and return, when told to) the correct contents of c4, but does not recognize this value in the conditional statement.

I have seen condition statements in javascript use both `==` and `===`. Not sure if there is any difference, tried both. Tried single and double quotation marks.

Posting on the good sheets forum, which requested I cross post.

Comment: Have you tried console.logging the output?  Every once in a while especially with spreadsheets there might be extra spaces or other things within the c4 column that might be screwing it up.  Otherwise I think I would need to see either that section of the spreadsheet, and how you are passing information to the function, with the rest of the function.

Comment: `===` does a more strict equality comparison, as noted in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 1):

May be intended/irrelevant but I noticed you have an extra ` in your code.

```
function commission(platform, amount) {
 if(platform == "AB"){
  return amount;
 }
 else
 {
  return 0; /// insert your own return
 }
};
```

Google spreadsheet screenshot of solution

[image]

Comment: I assumed that it was irrelevant as the grave accent is used here to apply code formatting, so I removed it from the question.